# How to fetch data from database and export to csv file using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, typescript

i need to fetch data from database to csv file. I am able to fetch all data but couldnt fetch data which is in object format, it displays as [object object] in csv file.

**TS file:**

```
getData() {
   let source = this.resultList;
   let destination = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
         let entry = new Entry();
         entry.id = source[i]['id'];
         entry.participantId = source[i]['participantId'];
         entry.completedOn = moment(source[i]['completedOn']).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
          if (typeof source[i]['satisfaction'] == 'string') {
              entry['satisfaction'] = source[i]['satisfaction']
            } else {
                for (var property in source[i]['satisfaction']) {
                    if (source[i]['satisfaction'].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                     entry[property] = source[i]['satisfaction'][property]
                    }
            }
          }
         destination.push(entry);
     }
     return destination;
    }
  }
```

I am unable to fetch objects present in "prodandService" to csv file, it displays as [object object] instead displaying items.

**JSON data:**

{"satisfaction":{"prodandService":[{"index":"Orbiz"},{"index":"qwerq"},{"index":"asfd"},{"index":"test"},{"index":"test123"},{"index":"TestWD"},{"index":"IOS app"},{"index":"Lipstick"},{"index":"Foundation"},{"index":"lipstick"},{"index":"Website"},{"index":"App IOS"},{"index":"Shampoo Vanilla"},{"index":"Shampoo Strawberry"},{"index":"car"},"Lipstick"],"price":"medium","customer":"yes","recomondation":"4","sales":["phone"],"phoneVist":"3","importance":["Quality"],"frequence":"quarter","satisfaction":"3"},"completedOn":"2017-08-28T09:39:54.676Z","id":10,"participantId":217}

Please Help.

Comment: Also don't forget to parse your object from your request, to make it an object with the `.json()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library to export to a CSV file, which worked great for me :

I've been using an external library to be able to export documents from my Angular4 app : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Here is the sample code I used to extract my data. I binded this method to a button to trigger the event :

**TypeScript component : (EDITED)**

```
  // Notice the parameters from the service call that give me back my filtered datas
  exportDatas(documentType: string) {
    // I believe you store your service data you want to export in this.resultList
    let source = this.resultList;
    const blob = new Blob([source.blob()]);
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'Export.' + documentType);
  }
```

**Template side : (EDITED)**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="exportDatas('csv')" type="button">CSV</button>
  <button (click)="exportDatas('pdf')" type="button">PDF</button>
</div>
```

---

Works great, and code is simpler to maitain.

**EDIT :**

Use NPM to install :

- `npm install file-saver --save`
- `npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev` (Types if you need them, I didn't use them)

and import in your component (I'm using Angular-CLI) :

- Without types : `import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';`
- With types (not tested but I believe it's correct) : `import { FileSaver } from 'file-saver';`

Comment: Thanks for the response, do i need to write API for this?

Comment: No you don't, you just need to call the `.saveAs()` method with the data you want to extract into the desired format.

Comment: Well, I gave all the code I could... I edited the code to add the imports and package.json but after that you have to integrate it yourself to your project...

Comment: I edited the Component and Template part to be more like your code, and added the explanations to install the library ? Idk what I can do appart from that

Comment: Thank you so much.. i am struck somewhere, but your links helped me